# Is there a way to resize a Libgdx window based on the monitor's maximum bound?

Tags: java, libgdx, window, resize, awt

What I mean is there a way to set the window size to related to the result given by this method: **GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds()** ? This gives back a different result compared to Gdx.graphics.getWidth() and Gdx.graphics.getHeight(): these return the screen size, but what I'd like to have is the screen area - menu bars area (for example the Dock on a Mac). I'd also like to keep the ratio of the window while doing so.

I tried to use the Java.awt method GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds(), but it couldn't run. I was looking on google and people say that using Java.awt methods with Libgdx causes problems, so I presume that's why.

[Main code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3RBs.png)
[Debug view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdyBP.gif)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want the window to be maximised on start then you can set that directly in the `Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration config` with

`config.setMaximised(true);`

You can maximise after the start with (which is going below the abstraction libGDX provides).

`GLFW.glfwMaximizeWindow(window.getWindowHandle);`

https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/window_guide.html#window_sizelimits

You can capture the window with a listener on config.

```
config.setWindowListener(new Lwjgl3WindowAdapter() {

@Override
public void created(final Lwjgl3Window window) {
```

If you need in the program to know what the available dimensions is without menu bars etc (which is the equivalent of AWT `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds()`  then

`GLFW.glfwGetMonitorWorkarea​(long monitor, int[] xpos, int[] ypos, int[] width, int[] height);`

using
`GLFW.glfwGetPrimaryMonitor()`

and then you can build a custom window maximiser with

```
GLFW.glfwSetWindowPos​(long window, int xpos, int ypos);
GLFW.glfwSetWindowSize​(long window, int width, int height);
```

https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/glfw/GLFW.html

Comment: I've done the following:`IntBuffer xpos_b, ypos_b, width_b, height_b;
  int value = 1;
  xpos_b = ypos_b = width_b = height_b = IntBuffer.allocate(value);
  GLFW.glfwGetMonitorWorkarea(GLFW.glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), xpos_b, ypos_b, width_b, height_b); ` but it gives me an error: "Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1". I'm not sure if I'm doing things correctly. Is there anyway you can help?

Comment: can you get more info running with --debug or --stackrace option? try looking at this sequence https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69608970/lwjgl-3-glfw-window-crash  (especially if you are on mac).

Comment: Does this help?

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.lwjgl.system.Checks.check(Checks.java:100)
 at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.nglfwGetMonitorWorkarea(GLFW.java:1127)
 at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwGetMonitorWorkarea(GLFW.java:1158)

Comment: http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=6267.0
Looks like this is a null check for the window.

Also from here on Steam this seems to be something that happens with dual monitor setups
https://steamcommunity.com/app/979110/discussions/1/3006675644855488396/

Did you try following the sequence with glfwInit() before the other calls?

Comment: Connected with the steam issue above, it might be connected with difficulties connected with the detection of the primary monitor.
http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=5888.0
There are some things to try here. Summary seems to be that you need a workaround for an issue with the detection of your primary monitor.

Comment: Also the source should be attached to your project so you can put a breakpoint on that check(monitor) method and direcly debug from there, you can open GLFW and then work out at what point this null is assigned.

Comment: I think i's giving me errors because the GLFW.glfwGetPrimaryMonitor() method returns back a 0. It seems like GLFW is using a invokeP method that doesn't get found by a class called NativeLibraries.java. Does that say something to you?

Comment: Can you put your code in another question. Are you doing this in the main thread? On a mac? So for some reason your primary monitor isn't detected and the crash is because 0 isn't a valid monitor. Can you try with only one monitor and see if that works.

Comment: Yeah, I've just tried to run it on my MacBook now, without a monitor connected, and it still gives me 0. I'll add an animated gif now.

Comment: I found a way to get the primary monitor, but the main method is still not working

GLFW.glfwGetMonitorWorkarea(((Lwjgl3Graphics.Lwjgl3Monitor) Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration.getPrimaryMonitor()).getMonitorHandle(), xpos_b, ypos_b, width_b, height_b);